# Rx.Net - disposing of resources created during Observable.Create()

Tags: c#, .net, observable, system.reactive

I am trying to use Rx(.net) for a project and I have an issue with how to properly dispose resources that are created during `Observable.Create()` and emitted with `OnNext()`. My setup looks like this (shortened to the relevant bits only, hopefully):

```
var obs = Observable.Create<ReactiveRunData>(async (o) =>
  {
    if (someCondition)
    {
      RunData runData = await CreateRunData(); // RunData is IDisposable, needs to be disposed
      o.OnNext(runData);
    }

    o.OnCompleted();

    return Disposable.Empty;
  })
  .Concat(Observable.Empty<RunData>().Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)))
  .Repeat() // Resubscribe indefinitely after source completes
  .Publish().RefCount() // see http://northhorizon.net/2011/sharing-in-rx/
  ;
```

This is my implementation of an observable collection that's infinite and produces an item (of type `RunData`) every 2 seconds.

Then I do the actual reactive stuff by transforming the IObservable stream using all kinds of operators:

```
var final = obs
    .Select(runData => ...)
    // lots of other operations
    .Select(tuple => (tuple.runData, tuple.result));`
```

The final observable returns a tuple `(RunData, Result)`.

When subscribing to that observable, at the end I explicitly dispose of the `RunData` instances, like so:

```
final.Subscribe(
    async (tuple) =>
    {
        var (runData, result) = tuple;
        try
        {
            // ... do something with result and runData, await some stuff, ...
            
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            // error handling
        } finally 
        {
            // dispose of runData
            runData.Dispose();
        }
    },
    (Exception e) =>
    {
        // error handling
    });
```

I suspect this implementation is leaky in various ways, such as when exceptions are thrown from different places, in some cases of which I believe the RunData instance won't get disposed, but is just gone, replaced by an exception travelling through the pipe.

I believe I'd also run into problems if I would add a second subscriber to my observable, right? I don't need more than one subscriber, but that also makes me question my implementation.

I feel like the whole idea of passing data that needs to be disposed by subscribers is wrong, but I couldn't come up with a better way. I tried using `Observable.Using()`, but afaik that only disposes the resource when the sequence ends, which in my case is never. And I really need an infinite sequence because I want to be able to use functionality like `Scan()` to reference previous data to build intermediate data structures over time.

I also tried using the callback that is returned from the lambda of `Observable.Create()` but that fires as soon as Observable.Create() is done and not after the subscriber is done, so that led to race conditions (but I'm not even sure if I understood that correctly, RX + async is tricky).

So... how can I implement this properly?

For some background info, `RunData` includes (among other things) a DB transaction and an Autofac `LifetimeScope`, both of which I want to use throughout the pipeline, and both of which need to be disposed at the end, after the subscriber is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several issues that prevent it being safe to use in a production environment. I'll try to go thru them all, but I'll hit the most major design issue first.

When using `IDisposable` objects in C#, you have two ways to manage lifetime.

1. Either the creator of the `IDisposable` must call `Dispose()`,
2. Or, you're writing a factory method, so the consumer must call `Dispose()`.

That's not specifically about observables, that's whenever, anyway, and at all times, when you create disposables in C#.

Now, when an observable returns disposables then you are effectively writing a factory method, so the creator cannot call `Dispose()`.

But, you have no control of how many subscribers there are for your observable, so none of the consumers (observers/subscriptions) can know when they are done with the disposable.

The bottom-line is that you CANNOT safely manage disposables if they are the output of an observable. DO NOT DO IT.

Rx does offer a safe way of dealing with disposables that allows the pipeline to effectively manage the disposables lifetime - and that's with the `Using` operator. That's what you should use.

Before I give an example, I'll just cover off on the 3 other issue I see in your code.

1. You use external state with your `if (someCondition)`. External state is bad in observables and you should learn to avoid it always. It's hard to tell what you're using this for in your code, so I'll ignore this issue for now.
2. You're using a `async` in the `Create` call - while that's OK for create as there is a `Func<IObserver<T>, Task<IDisposable>>` overload, I'm always suspicious of this kind of code as the framework converts `Func<Task>` into `Action` as fire-and-forget calls - and these are hard to debug. Try to avoid!
3. You're returning `Disposable.Empty` inside the `Create`. Whenever you do this it is likely that you're doing something wrong. Often this creates code that you cannot cancel and/or that creates deadlocks. There are very few times that you need to resort to `Create` in this way. Try to avoid!

From your code in the question it appears that `RunData` produces a result. I'll assume that there is a `GetResult()` method on `RunData` that produces a value of type `Result`.

To start, since `CreateRunData` is `async` you should add this handy helper method:

```
public static class ObservableEx
{
    public static IObservable<T> Using<T, R>(Func<Task<R>> resourceFactory, Func<R, IObservable<T>> observableFactory) where R : IDisposable =>
        from r in Observable.FromAsync(resourceFactory)
        from t in Observable.Using(() => r, observableFactory)
        select t;
}
```

Here are the two ways that I would write your code.

(1)

```
IObservable<Result> obs =
    ObservableEx
        .Using(
            () => CreateRunData(),
            rd =>
                Observable
                    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0))
                    .Where(t => someCondition) // don't do this
                    .Select(t => rd.GetResult()))
        .Publish()
        .RefCount();
```

This approach creates one instance of your resource and continues to use it until all of your subscribers have disposed of their subscriptions.

(2)

```
IObservable<Result> obs =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0))
        .Where(t => someCondition) // don't do this
        .SelectMany(t =>
            ObservableEx
                .Using(
                    () => CreateRunData(),
                    rd => Observable.Return(rd.GetResult())))
        .Publish()
        .RefCount();
```

This version creates a new resource for each tick pf the `Interval`.

Should `GetResult` actually be `async` then do these replacements:

(1)

Replace `.Select(t => rd.GetResult()))` with `.SelectMany(t => Observable.FromAsync(() => rd.GetResultAsync())))`.

(2)

Replace `rd => Observable.Return(rd.GetResult())))` with `rd => Observable.FromAsync(() => rd.GetResultAsync())))`.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer this! It helped me a lot in understanding RX better. In my own uninformed attempts, I just couldn't get Using() to work correctly for my usecase, but with your suggestions, I'm positive I can work it out! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This would be easily solved if all return type of operators during your pipe are all IDisposable (and dispose RunData under the hood), which should be logic in what you try to achieve.

```
Observable
    .FromAsync<MemoryStream>(async => Task.FromResult(new MemoryStream()))
    .Select(d => Observable.Return(d)
                           // Run  dangerous operators here  
                           .Select(s => new FileStream("r", FileMode.Open))
                           // Catch and return IDisposable if error
                           .Catch((Exception ex) => Observable.Return((IDisposable) d)))
    .Switch() 
    .Do(d => d.Dispose()) // Dispose will be always called
    .Repeat() 
    .Subscribe();
```

**Note** :

- I just replace your `IDisposable` object with `MemoryStream()` for the example and use FromAsync operator instead of create
- The higher order observable is here to avoid breaking the subscription during the catch

Comment: There's some great suggestions in your example: 
1) using a higher order observable to be able to access the `d` from inside the catch, very useful! Was wondering how to do that.
2) turning the exceptions into disposables sounds like a good idea too!

But: your code uses `Do()` instead of the `Subscribe()` callback, yet I need to access `runData` in there (I clarified my code above). So disposing before the Subscribe callback ends won't work I think.
And I still need to ensure that `runData` is passed all the way to subscribe to dispose it, otherwise I'm still leaking. Not ideal :(

Comment: I had a go at your higher-order exception handling pattern, but it seems I stumbled onto another problem with that. I asked it as a separate question, maybe you know an answer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74180868/rx-net-catching-exceptions-and-higher-order-observables

Comment: Please don't do this solution. It's a bad idea.